# Scaling a radial gradient makes it change its location

Tags: flutter

I am trying to scale a radial gradient in a BoxDecoration but when I do `scale(1.5, 1.0, 1.0)` it changes the current position of the gradient.
Should I also translate it to fix the current horizontal position?
If yes, then what calculation should I do?

```dart
BoxDecoration(
  gradient: RadialGradient(
    transform: MyTransform()
  )
)

class MyTransform extends GradientTransform {
  Matrix4 transform(Rect bounds, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return Matrix4.identity()
      ..scale(2.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  }
}
```

Comment: `..translate(tr.dx, tr.dy)..scale(2.0, 1.0, 1.0)..translate(-tr.dx, -tr.dy)`

Comment: sorry, what should be tr.dx?

Comment: `tr` is an `Offset` that stays in the same place after scaling - for example if you want to see the central point of your gradient to stay in the same place then `tr` should be set to your gradient center

Comment: Thanks. But it didn't work. It still change its location. This is really bugging me out :(

Comment: so what is the value of `tr` in your case?

Comment: `Offset(bounds.width/2, bounds.height/2)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256331/discussion-between-jonathan-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink comments I was able to fix this.

Most examples of centering use only width/2 and height/2 which didn't work for me.
However `bounds.center` worked because the `RadialGradient` transform needs the left+width/2 and top+height/2 to be centered.